# Find if value is present in a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post controller that allows you to select a profession. I also have a work controller that has a list of professions stored seperated by commas. Eg:

Post has a row called profession, and only allows you to choose 1.

Work has a row called profession that are stored like this: business, law, accounting.

What I would like to do is once you save your post, take you to a page that shows work where Post profession is equal to Work profession. (Only relevant work show)

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use SQL LIKE queries,eg, Work.where("profession LIKE ?","%#{@post.profession}%")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like what you're trying to do.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @post = Post.create(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to some_other_path(post_id: @post.id)
  else
    # handle error
  end
end
```

**some_controller.rb**

```
def some_action
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @works = Work.where("profession like ?", "%#{@post.profession}%")
end
```

Since you're using Postgres, you can use `like` which will match patterns within a field. This is more of a search functionality than a way of associating records. So if you have a Post that has a profession of "market", the like would match "market" *and* "marketing".

It might prove to be cleaner and easier to have Profession be a separate model. Post could belong_to, and Work could have_many.

Comment: Hi thanks, the only problem I am having is where(profession: @post.profession) because the profession of the work is stored in a list like such: business, marketing, law whilst @post.profession is a single like "marketing". So I need to make it look to see if it finds it. How would I do that?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: that doesn't work. I think it is because the query is if profession like post.profession, and because profession can have several words like this "business, marketing" it wont find any like because @post.profession equals to 'marketing'. So if we were to swap it, it would work I believe?

Comment: That should work. Paste in what you're trying? Make sure you have the '%'; they're important.

Comment: I haven't tried anything that haven't resulted in errors beside the example you've shown. However as I said in theory I think I know what to do, however unable to write it :D